# How to fix lens "stuck" on Nikon D3100?

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, repair, nikon-d3100

My younger sister has a Nikon d3100. Now she asks me if I can help her fix it. She uses the lens that came with the d3100 kit, and for some reason it's completely stuck. She claims that it's been that way "forever".

The camera takes pictures fine, autofocus works and there are no apparent problems with the camera or lens. However, when I push the button to remove the lens, it goes halfway (out of the "click" that you can hear) but it will not come off. It doesn't go all the way around.

Any advice on how to fix this? I don't want to use force to try make it come off.. I suppose I could send it in to be fixed.. but would it be covered by warranty?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The camera should still be under warranty as it was bought not too long ago. Last spring if I remember it right. I'll send it in and see if they can do something about it. :)

Answer (score 3):

If the camera is still under warranty, your best bet is to send it in regardless of if the repair itself is covered or not, since fixing it yourself is likely to void the warranty.  It sounds like the latch is probably stuck or perhaps the button simply isn't actuating it.  They'll probably have to take the body apart to access the mechanism from behind.